# Disable DSUSP - Terminal Control

Tags: c, terminal

Firstly, what is DSUSP?

I'm trying to disable it using the following code line:

```
tntty.c_cc[VDSUSP] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;
```

But I get the error that "VDSUSP is undeclared"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux `termios(3)` man page describes it thus (emphasis mine):

> `VDSUSP` (not in POSIX; **not supported under Linux**; 031, EM,
>   Ctrl-Y) Delayed suspend character: send SIGTSTP signal when the 
>   character is  read  by  the  user  program.  Recognized when IEXTEN
>   and ISIG are set, and the system supports job control, and then not
>   passed as input.

As this isn't a POSIX-specified index, you should test for its presence and only attempt to disable it on platforms where it is defined:

```
#ifdef VDSUSP
tntty.c_cc[VDSUSP] = _POSIX_VDISABLE;  
#endif
```

Comment: Configure test? I think it would make more sense to just use `#ifdef VDSUSP` in the source...

Comment: @R.: Isn't it allowed to be an `enum` constant?

Comment: No. Per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html "The subscript values shall be suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives".